# I want to test a self written module for bindings

Tags: c#, unit-testing, binding, ninject

I want to unit-test if my kernel-module has all bindings set to the right target. To easiest way I found was to create a kernel with the module loaded, get every bound-type and check if it is the right one:

```
this.kernel = new StandardKernel(new MainKernelModule());
Assert.That(this.kernel.Get<IMyClass>() is MyClass);
```

But some classes depends on a connection to a server, which shouldn't be used in my unit-test. Thats why this classes can't be created by the kernel in the unit-test-environment.

My Question: How can I get the target class of a IBinding?

```
var module = new MainKernelModule();
var kernel = new StandardKernel(module);

foreach (IBinding binding in module.Bindings)
{
     // if (binding.BindingTarget is MyClass)
     // Debug.WriteLine("Yeah");
}
```

I hope someone could help me. Unfortunately I found nothing with google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't or can you tell me what's the target class of

```
Bind<IFoo>().ToMethod(ctx=> IsItSunny() ? New SunnyFoo() : BadWeatherFoo())
```

What we do usually is not to test the bindings directly. But to write integration tests, where we replace the interface classes to other systems e.g DB access or web services by mocks and test the system functionality. this detects almost all binding problems. The small risk of wrong bindings to the foreign systems is detected realy fast when you do the manual integration tests.